# how to add scrollview dynamically in android

Tags: android

I have android code the display a list of users information , and sometime it needs to have a scroll bar to display all users ?? and sometimes not.. how can i set scrolllayout dynamically not in xml layout file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your question is on how to do this dynamically, but in your case you should just encapsulate the view in a ScrollView in XML. If the content isn't large enough to require scrolling, it won't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with wrapping xml layout in a scroll view? If you wrap it in the scrollview the scroll will be there when you need it, is it causing problems when you dont need it?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it with a `scrollview` anyways.  It won't show the scrollbars unless it needs them.